# Does select all records work in cassandra when one node fails in RF=1 scenario?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

If I have 3 nodes and I have RF=1 and one node unavailable. Then if I use `select * from table` or `select * from table where secondary_index=x`, will it fail or return partial data?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the replication factor to be 1..I guess it will fail for either of the cases,if a partition to be obtained belongs to the node that is down.

**Case 1:** You are doing a select of all partitions for a column family. If all the partitions are split across the two available nodes, your read is safe. If any one of the row partition is there in the unavailable node, you are bound to get an exception.

**Case 2:** Agreed that secondary indexes are local but in order to apply the secondary index without any partition key, the coordinator has to go around the local indexes of all the nodes to find that out(If am not wrong). So , that will practically end up in a sure shot exception as cassandra may assume that the partition in the down node may contain the secondary index value attached with it.

My suggestion : Dont use this replication factor or querying pattern if you are going for production set up!!